# Проверка электронной подписи, СМЭВ

Tags: xml, java, soap

Здравствуйте, снова вопрос по ЭЦП.

Отправляю на сервис подписанный SOAP пакет, постоянно возвращается ответ, что подпись неверна. Подпись генерирую при помощи JCP криптопро, контейнер точно рабочий, сертификат доверенный.

```
SignatureValueType svt = new SignatureValueType();

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
SignatureClass.ObjectFactory f_2 = new SignatureClass.ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement sit_jaxb = f_2.createSignedInfo(sit);

try {
    Node node = SOAPFactory.newInstance().createElement("SignedInfo");
    WriterClass.writeDocumentToSoap(sit_jaxb, node);
    Source xmlSource2 = new DOMSource(node);
    Result outputTarget2 = new StreamResult(outputStream2);
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.transform(xmlSource2, outputTarget2);
    Init.init();
    Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
    InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream2.toByteArray());
    byte[] bb = canon.canonicalize(outputStream2.toByteArray());
    byte[] signval = sign("CryptoProSignature", key, bb);
    svt.setValue(signval);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
sgt.setSignatureValue(svt);
```

SignedInfo задаётся следующим образом:

```
DigestMethodType dmt = new DigestMethodType();
dmt.setAlgorithm("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gostr3411");

ReferenceType rt2 = new ReferenceType();
rt2.setURI("#body");
rt2.setDigestMethod(dmt);
rt2.setTransforms(trst);
////Пункт 7
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(bodyNode);
Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
try {
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    Init.init();

    Canonicalizer canon = Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS);
    InputStream is = canon.canonicalize(outputStream.toByteArray());

    rt2.setDigestValue(computeDigestWithStream(is));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//////////
sit.getReference().add(rt2);

sgt.setSignedInfo(sit);
```

bodyNode - это элемент body из тела сообщения.

После всех операций возвращаю SecurityHeaderType sht = f_0.createSecurityHeaderType();

```
sht.getAny().add(sgt);
sht.getAny().add(tst);
sht.getAny().add(bstt);

//
return f_0.createSecurity(sht);
```

И анмаршаллером записываю в xml.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда мне смотреть. Сам первый раз с этим столкнулся и просто не знаю уже. Техподдержка СМЭВ говорит, что проблема может быть в том, что xml-документ изменяется после подписания. Почему это может происходить? Может, не выносить подписывание в отдельный класс, а сделать его там же, где генерируется сообщение? Может быть, проблема где-то в анмаршаллинге? Понимаю, что вопрос специфический, но если кто-нибудь сможет хотя бы указать направление, буду бесконечно благодарен.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл косяк:

```
Node node = SOAPFactory.newInstance().createElement("SignedInfo");
            WriterClass.writeDocumentToSoap(sit_jaxb, node);
```

Создаётся элемент `SignedInfo`, в который пишется элемент `SignedInfo` с потоками.

Т.е. получаем

```
<SignedInfo>
 <SignedInfo xmlns=...>
  ...
 </SignedInfo>
</SignedInfo>
```

И правда, чем разбираться в чужом коде лучше было написать свой.

Comment: Только вот все равно она неправильная получается. Уже что не пробовал, не вижу просто где глобальный такой косяк у меня.
Может ли при переводе в InputStream косячить кириллическкие символы? Хотя там же UTF-8, не должно ведь?